# Using Jquery $(this) in Meteor

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, meteor, self

How can I use the this function in meteor?  for example, I want to be able to click on any given

element and find out what its class is.  Also, how can I get information on the item that I click on with Meteor?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Let's say somewhere in the code you have a template handling events:

```
Template.tmpl_name.events = {
  'click #logo': function (e) {
    // Instead of using $(this), you can do:
    var $this = $(e.target);
    // Your usual code here, e.g.:
    console.log($this.attr('href'));
  }
};
```